# Concatenate all columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple pandas dataframe which may have different number of columns and the number of these columns typically vary from 50 to 100. I need to create a final column that is simply all the columns concatenated. Basically the string in the first row of the column should be the sum(concatenation) of the strings on the first row of all the columns. I wrote the loop below but I feel there might be a better more efficient way to do this. Any ideas on how to do this

```
num_columns = df.columns.shape[0]
col_names = df.columns.values.tolist()
df.loc[:, 'merged'] = ""
for each_col_ind in range(num_columns):
    print('Concatenating', col_names[each_col_ind])
    df.loc[:, 'merged'] = df.loc[:, 'merged'] + df[col_names[each_col_ind]]
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Solution with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), but output is `float`, so convert to `int` and `str` is necessary:

```
df['new'] = df.sum(axis=1).astype(int).astype(str)
```

Another solution with `apply` function `join`, but it the slowiest:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(''.join, axis=1)
```

Last very fast `numpy solution` - convert to `numpy array` and then ['sum'](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html):

```
df['new'] = df.values.sum(axis=1)
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', '3'], 'B': ['4', '5', '6'], 'C': ['7', '8', '9']})
#[30000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)

cols = list('ABC')

#not_a_robot solution
In [259]: %timeit df['concat'] = pd.Series(df[cols].fillna('').values.tolist()).str.join('')
100 loops, best of 3: 17.4 ms per loop

In [260]: %timeit df['new'] = df[cols].astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 386 ms per loop

In [261]: %timeit df['new1'] = df[cols].values.sum(axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.5 ms per loop

In [262]: %timeit df['new2'] = df[cols].astype(str).sum(axis=1).astype(int).astype(str)
10 loops, best of 3: 68.6 ms per loop
```

EDIT If dtypes of some columns are not `object` (obviously `string`s) cast by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df['new'] = df.astype(str).values.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to only concatenate the last 20 columns but only concatenate a particular column if there is data? Also, i would want to have a delimiter in place so when you're looking at your overall column, you can see how it's broken out.

Answer (score 24):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', '3'], 'B': ['4', '5', '6'], 'C': ['7', '8', '9']})

df['concat'] = pd.Series(df.fillna('').values.tolist()).str.join('')
```

Gives us:

```
df
Out[6]: 
   A  B  C concat
0  1  4  7    147
1  2  5  8    258
2  3  6  9    369
```

To select a given set of columns:

```
df['concat'] = pd.Series(df[['A', 'B']].fillna('').values.tolist()).str.join('')

df
Out[8]: 
   A  B  C concat
0  1  4  7     14
1  2  5  8     25
2  3  6  9     36
```

However, I've noticed that approach can sometimes result in `NaN`s being populated where they shouldn't, so here's another way:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> df['concat'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, x), axis=1)
>>> df
   A  B  C concat
0  1  4  7    147
1  2  5  8    258
2  3  6  9    369
```

Although it should be noted that this approach is a lot slower:

```
$ python3 -m timeit 'import pandas as pd;from functools import reduce; df=pd.DataFrame({"a": ["this", "is", "a", "string"] * 5000, "b": ["this", "is", "a", "string"] * 5000});[df[["a", "b"]].apply(lambda x: reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, x)) for _ in range(10)]'
10 loops, best of 3: 451 msec per loop
```

Versus

```
$ python3 -m timeit 'import pandas as pd;from functools import reduce; df=pd.DataFrame({"a": ["this", "is", "a", "string"] * 5000, "b": ["this", "is", "a", "string"] * 5000});[pd.Series(df[["a", "b"]].fillna("").values.tolist()).str.join(" ") for _ in range(10)]'
10 loops, best of 3: 98.5 msec per loop
```

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using a more recent version of python, but I copied exactly what you had and it did not work. Dataframe and all. I'm using version 3.7.0

Answer (score 16):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm building my answer off of blacksite's response.

For clarity, LunchBox commented that it failed for Python 3.7.0. It also failed for me on Python 3.6.3. Here is the original answer by blacksite:

```
df['concat'] = pd.Series(df.fillna('').values.tolist()).str.join('')
```

Here is my modification for Python 3.6.3:

```
df['concat'] = pd.Series(df.fillna('').values.tolist()).map(lambda x: ''.join(map(str,x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, @bodily. I ended up in the same scenario and your answer helped me.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions given above that use numpy arrays have worked great for me.

However, one thing to be careful about is the indexing when you get the `numpy.ndarray` from `df.values`, since the axis labels are removed from `df.values`.

So to take one of the solutions offered above (the one that I use most often) as an example:

```
df['concat'] = pd.Series(df.fillna('').values.tolist()).str.join('')
```

This portion:

```
df.fillna('').values
```

does not preserve the indices of the original `DataFrame`.  Not a problem when the `DataFrame` has the common `0, 1, 2, ...` row indexing scheme, but this solution will not work when the `DataFrame` is indexed in any other way.   You can fix this by adding an `index=` argument to `pd.Series()`:

```
df['concat'] = pd.Series(df.fillna('').values.tolist(), 
                         index=df.index).str.join('')
```

I always add the `index=` argument just to be safe, even when I'm sure the `DataFrame` is row-indexed as `0, 1, 2, ...`

Comment: how to avoid Na values here

Answer (score 2):

This lambda approach offers some **flexibility** with **columns chosen** and **separator type**:

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', '3'], 'B': ['4', '5', '6'], 'C': ['7', '8', '9']})

    A   B   C
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

Concatenate **All Columns - no separator**:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df['combined'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: ''.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)

    A   B   C   combined
0   1   4   7   147
1   2   5   8   258
2   3   6   9   369
```

Concatenate **Two Columns A and C with '_' separator**:

```
cols = ['A', 'C']
df['combined'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)

    A   B   C   combined
0   1   4   7   1_7
1   2   5   8   2_8
2   3   6   9   3_9
```

Answer (score 0):

as a solution to @Gary Dorman's question in the comment,
`i would want to have a delimiter in place so when you're looking at your overall column, you can see how it's broken out.`

you maybe use

```py
df_tmp=df.astype(str) + ','
df_tmp.sum(axis=1).str.rstrip(',')
```

before:

```
1.2.3.480tcp
6.6.6.680udp
7.7.7.78080tcp
8.8.8.88080tcp
9.9.9.98080tcp
```

after:

```
1.2.3.4,80,tcp
6.6.6.6,80,udp
7.7.7.7,8080,tcp
8.8.8.8,8080,tcp
9.9.9.9,8080,tcp
```

which looks better (like CSV :)
This additional sep step is about 30% slower in my machine.

Comment: Please note that creating CSV in this way may result in invalid formats. For example, when the separator token is used in a field.