# To append the column values of the csv

Tags: python, loops, append, python-3.6, python-3.5

I have a csv which has the 500 columns .I want to append the values of one column after the other.

The csv is as follows

```
A B  
0 3 
1 4 
2
```

The output must be in the following format

```
A 
0
1
2
3
4
```

That means the large number of column values are to be appended in just one column .

Comment: what have you attempted so far? are you having a specific problem with the code you have written? can you post your code and detail the errors with it?

Comment: do you need to concat all columns from the csv to one, so something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786804/concatenate-all-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:-

```
#importing helping module(s)
import pandas as pd

#reading the csv data
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/csv")

#converting into numpy array
base = df.values.T

#converting to pandas series obj
base = pd.Series(base.ravel())

#filterning out nan values
base = base.dropna().values
print(base)
```

Comment: i am getting an error TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''@Vicrobot

Comment: @arpita I've updated my answer, so that non-native dtypes would also be processed.

Comment: @Vicrobot: why do you import `numpy`?